# Use txt file as source for URLs - Python

Tags: python

I have a script that access an url and retrieve data like this:

```
 usock = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com.br')
#Reads the page
    data = usock.read()
    usock.close()
#Search for links
    links = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', data)
```

And I would like to use a txt file as source for urls, I already have a txt file with urls by line like this:

```
http://www.google.com.br/
http://www.recrutamento.com.br/
```

I was trying to use this file with this code, but I always get `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

here is where I get stuck:

```
os.chdir("C:\Python27")
urls = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'ord.txt'), 'r').readlines()
for url in urls:
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
#Reads the page
    data = usock.read()
    usock.close()
```

It displays exactly the correct path and file name:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: C:\\Python27\\ord.txt
```

Comment: Where is ord.txt? I bet it isn't at `C:\Python27\ord.txt`

Comment: yes it is there, but it can´t find it, before i was trying without the os.chdir, but even with this it cannot find.

Comment: Either you mispelled the  name of the file or it is somewhere else(check your desktop) .

Comment: @Azwr I mispelled the name, my file was named as ord.txt.txt that´s why it wasn't working. sorry guys

Comment: other remark: you don't need to join the path with the current working directory, `open()` already works relative to the current working directory, so `open('ord.txt')` is enough (if the file indeed exists in the cwd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
os.chdir("C:\\Python27")
```

or

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Python27")
```

will solve it (notice the double backslash `\\` in the first option and the `r` prefix in the second one).

Explanation:
You can read here http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals about escape sequences in Python.